# Is it possible to bypass the 32 limit when using azure webjob and queue?

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-queues

I am learning azure webjob and queue, in the company I work for, every night, we calculate like 7 million records. The calculation is quite simple, but the quantity is quite big (as there around 7 million records in db).

As the company is moving to Azure, I am wondering can azure queue be used to handle this? In theory, I can create some code to populate the queue (as there is a 64kb message size limit, I guess I can put like 10 records in one message,
so total message will be like 700k?). Then I will have webjob that triggered by the queue and do the calculation.

However, according to [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/),there is a max limit of 32 in message retrieving.

Does this mean that there will be a maximum of 32 webjob triggered concurrently?If that is the case, 700000/32 = 21875, which means it will take quite a while to finish.

Is there a way to trigger more webjob to run concurrently other than the 32 limit?

Answer (score 1):

You can get much higher concurrency by combining `BatchSize` and `NewBatchThreshold`. The best way to look at it is that the concurrency limit is the sum of the two flags. So if you leave `BatchSize` at 32 and set `NewBatchThreshold` to 100, the concurrency limit will be 132.

See https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/628 more for details.